A statement: If $b \gt a \gt 0$ then $b^2 \gt a^2 \gt 0$. What is the contrapositive of this statement?
A statement:

If $b \gt a \gt 0$ then $b^2 \gt a^2 \gt 0$.

for example

If $x \gt 2 \gt 0$ then $x^2 \gt 4 \gt 0  $ which is true for all $x \in \Bbb R$

We all know that

If $x^2 \leq 4$ then $-2 \leq x \leq 2$.

The second statement does not look like the contrapositive of the first statement.
I am a bit confused
What is the contrapositive of the statement If $b \gt a \gt 0$ then $b^2 \gt a^2 \gt 0$?
and
What is the contrapositive of the statement If $x \gt 2 \gt 0$ then $x^2 \gt 4 \gt> 0$?
thx

Original statement (if $P$, then $Q$):

If $x$ is greater than $2$, then $x^2$ is greater than $4$.

Here, $P$ is the statement "$x$ is greater than $2$" and $Q$ is the statement "$x^2$ is greater than $4$."
Contrapositive (if not $Q$, then not $P$):

If $x^2$ is not greater than $4$, then $x$ is not greater than $2$.

Now convert this back to mathematical notation:
If $x^2 \le 4$, then $x \le 2$.  And this is true because the original statement is true.
So, what about your statement that if $x^2 \le 4$, then $-2 \le x \le 2$?  This is also true, but it is not the contrapositive of the original statement, because the original statement does not also encompass the case $x < -2$.  In other words, although $x < 2$ implies $x^2 > 4$, the statement $P$ does not include all of the values of $x$ for which $Q$ is true.  So even though $x^2 \le 4$ does not allow us to say $x < -2$, the values that it does allow are included in the inequality $x \le 2$.  Another example of this reasoning is if $a = 1$, then it is also true that $a \le 100$.  But if $a \le 100$, it doesn't imply that $a = 1$.

How about the contrapositive of this statement: If b > a > 0 then $b^2 > a^2> 0$?

@StatsCruncher Why not try writing it out for yourself, and see what you get?  It might be good practice.

if $b^2<=a^2$ or $a^2<=0$ then if $b<=a$ or $a<=0$ Is it correct?

@StatsCruncher Yes, it is essentially correct, although you have an extra "if" statement.  It should read:  if $b^2 \le a^2$ or $a^2 \le 0$, then $b \le a$ or $a \le 0$.

The contrapositive of the statement

If $x > 2$ then $x^2 > 4$

is

If $x^2 \leq 4$ then $x \leq 2$

The statement

If $x^2 \leq 4$ then $-2 \leq x \leq 2$

happens to also be true! But it is not the contrapositive of the first statement.

Of course it’s true! There is a stronger statement that is true.  It happens to be the contrapositive of a stronger original statement (hint: use absolute values in the hypothesis).
